# Circular shift of column values in excel

Tags: vba, excel

How can I perform circular shift of column values in excel ?

I tried:

```
Sub RowInsert()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.Cut
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

but its not working.. There is a way to do it without VB ?

Comment: Try to remove Application.ScreenUpdating = False and run the code step-by-step; that way you'll see what's going on.

Comment: I tested your code and couldn't reproduce your issue. The code worked as expected.

Comment: Yes, I checked it now and its working when the column is A1 and starting from cell number 1, what parameters should I change to change the column and the start cell number ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cycle your array in-place, you can do this instead. It's more efficient than inserting lines, cutting and pasting, and it will not mess up the rest of your sheet.

```
Dim arr As Variant
Dim temp As Variant
Dim r As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim n As Long

'Specify range
Set r = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown))
'Read range into a Variant array
arr = r.Value
'Count elements
n = UBound(arr, 1)
'Take bottom element and set aside
temp = arr(n, 1)
'Move each element down by 1, starting from bottom
For i = UBound(arr, 1) To 2 Step -1
    arr(i, 1) = arr(i - 1, 1)
Next i
'Put old bottom element in first place
arr(1, 1) = temp
'Write array back to sheet
r.Value = arr
```

Comment: Thanks !! Where in the code I need to change to start the cyclic shift from the second row?

Comment: Change both occurrences of `"A1"` to whatever the starting cell is.